# Type mismatch between the voltage table type and GPIO table

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, fstab, nouveau

I ran into this error this morning after booting into Windows, then switching back.

```
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: volt: 
Type mismatch between the voltage table type and the GPIO table.   
Fallback to GPIO mode
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

I edited the `(nouveau.modeset=0)` boot parameters, and I still got booted in emergency mode so I unset it. I saw someone say they fixed their problem by adding the `#` character in the fstab file, but they didn't say on which line it was. This is what mine looks like.

fstab:

[image: screenshot of fstab file]

Comment: Old computer ? Bios Battery empty?

Comment: It's an old computer yes, the date and time gets changed anytime the laptop battery gets removed so i reckon there's a problem with the cmos

Comment: I use a dell precision m4700, currently have Windows 10 and ubuntu 22.04 Lts installed on it and I'm currently using kubuntu

Comment: Replace the Bios battery !